# Object Sticks To The Floor When It Moves

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, rigid-bodies

When the object moves up and down sometimes it stays stuck on the floor. What is the reason for this? And I am using RigidBody2D and my code in FixedUpdate() method also I use box collider.

I mean when I start the game a few times, it sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't. I would be very happy if you could help. Thanks in advance.
So let me explain in more detail what I want to tell you in more detail, I want to move the obstacles up and down with the help of the code, that is, the obstacles change their direction when they touch every floor or ceiling, and they move up and down, that is, when they hit each ceiling or floor, their directions change.but sometimes obstacles stick to the ceiling or floor when they need to change direction

[image]

Comment: Please put relevant portions of your code in the question to help people understand what might be going wrong. It would also help if you recorded a video and put a link to it. The problem at the moment is that it's very hard to work out what your mean at all.

Comment: i edited the question could you help  please

Answer (score 1):

I'd just make a fixed point for each game object to change direction instead of checking for collisions with a rigid body.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if(obstacle.transform.position.y + obstacle.transform.localScale.y > 
    upperPointOfReturn) 
    {
        obstacle.ChangeDirection();
    }

    if(obstacle.transform.position.y - obstacle.transform.localScale.y < 
    lowerPointOfReturn) 
    {
        obstacle.ChangeDirection();
    }

    obstacle.transform.position = new Vector2(
    obstacle.transform.position.y 
    + velocity* Time.deltaTime * direction, 0
    );
   
}

void ChangeDirection() {
    direction *= -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i thinks it's will help but *velocity  is my rigidbody velocity right

Comment: The code above is just an example how you could achieve a moving object without a rigidbody. If you provide more information I can workout a better code solution for you. And if your object is moving right just replace the y with x. But make sure, that your local scale is the correct one. (Long side of the object has to be the local scale)

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Physics Material 2D** with 0 Friction and 0 Bounciness and attach to the Player's Collider.

Comment: thanks for answer but i already did that and didn't work.